# How to add a WebcamPanel into a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, github, webcam, zxing

I have a program that can scan barcodes using your computer's webcam. This `WebcamPanel` works fine in a `JFrame` but when I enclose it to a `JPanel`, the `WebcamPanel` doesn't shows up anymore. Are there any other ways of just simply placing this `WebcamPanel` into a `JPanel`? Can I convert the `WebcamPanel` into a `JPanel` or vice versa?

Here are some of the code:

```
public class JFrame_Scanner extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable, ThreadFactory {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6441489157408381878L;

private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(this);

private Webcam webcam = null;
private WebcamPanel panel = null;
    public static String yeah = null;

public JFrame_Scanner() {

    super();
    initComponents();





    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Barcode Scanner");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

    webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);
    webcam.setViewSize(size);

    panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
    panel.setPreferredSize(size);



    Webcam_Panel.add(panel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    executor.execute(this);

}
```

Webcam_Panel is the `JPanel`.

panel is the `WebcamPanel`.

Comment: This confuses me greatly, `Webcam_Panel.add(panel);`, You say that Webcam_Panel is "the JPanel" yet I don't see where you declare a variable of it, create an instance of it, I don't see where you add it to any top level window. Is it a static variable? It kind of comes out of nowhere and disappears just as mysteriously. Please clarify your code and your situation.

Comment: Sir I'm using JFrame form in netbeans IDE and this `Webcam_Panel` is created from a palette.

Comment: Thank you for the updated information, but that still leaves unexplained my concerns. Even if you're using NetBeans, there must be code somewhere else that shows a variable declaration, an object creation, an addition to the top-level window. Else your question becomes a, "please explain why the code I'm not showing you isn't working" type question. As an aside, avoid using NetBeans code generation tools until you become familiar with how Swing works. Better at this state to create your GUI's by hand as it will make later use of the NetBeans tools much easier.

Comment: `public static javax.swing.JPanel Webcam_Panel;` here it is sir.

Comment: I hope you get an answer soon, but at this time I feel compelled to vote to place this question on hold pending posting of enough information to allow it to be answerable. You may wish to consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand the problem. Good luck.